# Dar replace nos chars de uma string

Tags: java

Bem, o título do tópico já diz tudo.

Tipo, eu tenho a `String a = "Banana é uma ótima fruta."`, como faço pra dar replace nos chars da palavra "Banana" ?

Eu queria que o replace ficasse, `"****** é uma ótima fruta."`.

Comment: pode explicar melhor que que quer realmente? é que com a informação não dá para perceber :)

Comment: A primeira resposta desse link pode te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702357/how-to-replace-a-substring-of-a-string

Answer (score 3):

Tenta isso:

```
public String mask(String template, String toMask) {
    int tamanho = toMask.length();
    StringBuilder replacement = new StringBuilder(tamanho);
    for (int t = 0; t < tamanho; t++) {
        replacement.add('*');
    }
    return template.replace(toMask, replacement);
}
```

E você usa assim:

```
String substituido = mask("Banana é uma ótima fruta.", "Banana");
```

Comment: @IgorVenturelli Muito bem observado. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "Banana é uma ótima fruta";

a = a.replace("Banana","******");

a // "****** é uma ótima fruta"
```

Utilize o método **replace** de String.